# Changing LocalDateTime based on time difference in current time zone vs. eastern time zone

Tags: java, datetime, timezone

Let's say one week ago I generate a LocalDateTime of 2015-10-10T10:00:00. Furthermore, let's assume I generate my current time zone id as such

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
String zoneId = timeZone.getId();  // "America/Chicago"
```

And my zoneId is "America/Chicago".

Is there an easy way I can convert my LocalDateTime to one for the time zone id "America/New_York" (ie so my updated LocalDateTime would be 2015-10-10T11:00:00)?

More importantly, is there a way I can convert my LocalDateTime to eastern time (ie, to a time zone with zoneId "America/New_York") no matter what time zone I am in? I am specifically looking for a way to do this with any LocalDateTime object generated in the past, and not necessarily for the current time this instant.

Comment: `LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));`

Comment: sorry, I'm specifically looking for a way to generate the time based on a LocalDateTime that I could have generated in the past. This would only get the current LocalDateTime.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

To convert a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) to another time zone, you first apply the original time zone using [`atZone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-), which returns a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), then convert to the new time zone using [`withZoneSameInstant()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-), and finally convert the result back to a `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime oldDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2015-10-10T10:00:00");
ZoneId oldZone = ZoneId.of("America/Chicago");

ZoneId newZone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
LocalDateTime newDateTime = oldDateTime.atZone(oldZone)
                                       .withZoneSameInstant(newZone)
                                       .toLocalDateTime();
System.out.println(newDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME));
```

```
2015-10-10T11:00:00
```

If you skip the last step, you'd keep the zone.

```
ZonedDateTime newDateTime = oldDateTime.atZone(oldZone)
                                       .withZoneSameInstant(newZone);
System.out.println(newDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME));
```

```
2015-10-10T11:00:00-04:00[America/New_York]
```