# Specify timezone of ZonedDateTime without changing the actual date

Tags: java, date, timezone, zoneddatetime

I have a Date object which holds a date (not current date) and I need to somehow specify that this date is UTC and then convert it to "Europe/Paris" which is +1 hours.

```
public static LocalDateTime toLocalDateTime(Date date){
    return ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneOffset.UTC), ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris")).toLocalDateTime();
}
```

Given a date of "2018-11-08 15:00:00" this converts the date into "2018-11-08 14:00:00". I need it to convert from UTC to Europe/Paris - not the other way around.

Comment: this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42280454/changing-localdatetime-based-on-time-difference-in-current-time-zone-vs-eastern

Comment: Why go through `LocalDateTime` when you can construct `ZonedDateTime` from `Instant` directly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use [`ZonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-) method to move from UTC to Paris time:

```
Date date = new Date();
ZonedDateTime utc = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
ZonedDateTime paris = utc.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));
System.out.println(utc);
System.out.println(paris);
System.out.println(paris.toLocalDateTime());
```

which prints:

```
2018-11-08T10:25:18.223Z
2018-11-08T11:25:18.223+01:00[Europe/Paris]
2018-11-08T11:25:18.223
```

Answer (score 1):

Since an old-fashioned `Date` object doesn’t have any time zone, you can ignore UTC completely and just convert to Europe/Paris directly:

```
private static final ZoneId TARGET_ZONE = ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris");

public static LocalDateTime toLocalDateTime(Date date){
    return date.toInstant().atZone(TARGET_ZONE).toLocalDateTime();
}
```

I’m not sure why you want to return a `LocalDateTime`, though. That is throwing away information. For most purposes I’d leave out `.toLocalDateTime()` and just return the `ZonedDateTime` from `atZone`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ZonedId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris");
 return ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(),zonedId);
```

Try to define ZoneId that is Europe/Paris